# User and Key Press Issues with Putty

Tags: ubuntu, putty, keys

Ubuntu Server newbie here, got some annoying issues with remote accessing my box with Putty. When I create a user and then login as that user, the terminal always starts with just '#' and not 'user@hostname:~#' which isn't useful where I want to see where I've changed directory too, like I can normally.

Also, when logged in as a user, I can't press the cursor keys to move the caret (blinking thing) around, or press up to see previously executed commands. Instead it gives me this representation of the button pressed: ^[[D ^[[A ^[[B ^[[C. Pressing Delete, too, gives me ^[[3~.

This is all strange to me, because when logged in as root, it all works fine. I'm hoping this is just something I've accidentally changed in Putty, or added the user wrongly, or perhaps just got caps lock on. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you login, try typing `bash` at the prompt to launch the bash shell.  It sounds like you're in the wrong shell (perhaps sh), even though bash should be the default.  As for setting the prompt, you'll want to look into setting the `PS1` environment variable.

Comment: He may need to change the shell permanently as suggested by Dennis Williamson.

Comment: Bash doesn't use `PROMPT`, but the Z shell can. Bash uses `PS1`.

Comment: You are absolutely right, Dennis.  My apologies... I haven't used bash in forever. x_x

Answer (score 2):

Bash should have line editing and a nice prompt set up by default. To set a more informative prompt, if it's not already, you can set the `PS1` environment variable:

```
PS1='\u@\h:\w\$ '
```

To change the user's login shell to Bash:

```
chsh -s /bin/bash username
```

or set it during the creation of the user:

```
adduser --shell /bin/bash (other options)
```

or by editing `/etc/adduser.conf` to set the default shell.

In your question, you show `#` as the prompt. That usually indicates the root user. It's best if you don't run as root. Login as a normal user and use `sudo` to perform administrative functions.

I would advise leaving the root user's shell set to `sh` and on the rare occasions that it's necessary to login as root, if you want to use Bash, just start it at the command line.

Comment: On some systems, the command is called `useradd` not `adduser` :)

Comment: @Khaled: True, but the OP said "Ubuntu" where `adduser` is a front end to `useradd`.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I just wanted to note that the command name may differ on other systems.